# Does Select() on a List lose track of the size of the collection?

Tags: c#, linq

In the following code, is the `Select()` method smart enough to keep the size of the list somewhere internally for the `ToArray()` method to be cheap?

```
List<Thing> bigList = someBigList;
var bigArray = bigList.Select(t => t.SomeField).ToArray();
```

Comment: The BCL source code is available from some Microsoft servers for your perusal for this sort of thing - ReSharper can automatically download and display them when you navigate to the class.

Comment: Mono checks for an ICollection, haven't looked whether that passes trough a Select, but it doesn't seem so. https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Linq/Enumerable.cs#L629

Comment: @Dykam Mono is a clean room implementation, no? That would make it useless for making statements about the performance of .NET

Comment: @Dykam, that's the Mono implementation, the .NET implementation is not necessarily the same...

Comment: @millimoose, they are implemented with similar behavior in mind, and I would be amazed if .Net would be slower in this respect.

Comment: @Dykam, anyway the OP asked about Select, not Count...

Comment: @dykam This is talking about optimisations. There's certainly ways to add more while preserving the same behaviour.

Comment: @d-b: My guess is that the a priori probability of the answer being **no** is pretty high. LINQ is implemented in a generally straightforward way, with very few optimisations. E.g. `Select()` merely returns a `yield return`-based IEnumerable, which doesn't support a fast`Count()` for `ToArray()` to use for this optimisation. To also address @dykam in here, it's thinkable that, say, Mono would instead make `Select()` return an `ICollection` where `Count()` defers to the underlying `IEnumerable`, `GetEnumerator()` does what the .NET version does, and the other methods are unsupported.

Comment: I am using this with the .Net implementation. The original source code is not particularly easy to go through, so I was wondering if anyone actually had looked into it before

Comment: @d--b I didn't get the question. Do you mean that does `Select` internally cache/pre-allocate array? or something else?

Comment: @millimoose: ok makes sense. I'll try to dig in the source code

Comment: @Ankush: well `List<T>.Count()` doesn't need to enumerate, so when you do `List<T>.ToArray()` it allocates the array once. IEnumerable<T> doesn't do that so it needs to be reallocating the results all the time which is expensive. I was wondering if List<T>().Select() created an object that kept track of the size of the collection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's easy to check, without looking at the implementation. Just create a class that implements `IList<T>`, and put a trace in the `Count` property:

```
    class MyList<T> : IList<T>
    {
        private readonly IList<T> _list = new List<T>();
        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return _list.GetEnumerator();
        }

        public void Add(T item)
        {
            _list.Add(item);
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            _list.Clear();
        }

        public bool Contains(T item)
        {
            return _list.Contains(item);
        }

        public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
        {
            _list.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
        }

        public bool Remove(T item)
        {
            return _list.Remove(item);
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("Count accessed");
                return _list.Count;
            }
        }

        public bool IsReadOnly
        {
            get { return _list.IsReadOnly; }
        }

        public int IndexOf(T item)
        {
            return _list.IndexOf(item);
        }

        public void Insert(int index, T item)
        {
            _list.Insert(index, item);
        }

        public void RemoveAt(int index)
        {
            _list.RemoveAt(index);
        }

        public T this[int index]
        {
            get { return _list[index]; }
            set { _list[index] = value; }
        }

        #region Implementation of IEnumerable

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

If the `Count` property is accessed, this code should print "Count accessed":

```
var list = new MyList<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var array = list.Select(x => x).ToArray();
```

But it doesn't print anything, so no, it doesn't keep track of the count. Of course there could be an optimization specific to `List<T>`, but it seems unlikely...

Comment: I like that you explained how you arrived at your answer.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: nice way of figuring that out! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

No, right now it does not (at least the .NET implementation). From the MS reference sources, `Enumerable.ToArray` is implemented as

```
public static TSource[] ToArray<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source"); 
    return new Buffer<TSource>(source).ToArray();
}
```

`Buffer<TSource>` creates a copy of the source sequence (in array form) on construction by iterating and resizing as necessary; it has a special "fast path" if `source` is an `ICollection<TSource>`, but the result of `Enumerable.Select` unsurprisingly does not implement that interface.

Be that as it may, apart from pure curiosity I don't think that this result means anything. For one, the implementation may change at any point in the future (even though a quick cost-benefit analysis won't find this likely). And in any case, you will suffer at most O(logN) reallocations. For small N the reallocations are not going to be noticeable. For large N, the amount of time spent on iterating over the collection is going to be O(N) and will therefore easily dominate.

Answer (score 1):

When you apply `Select` operator to enumerable sequence, it creates one of following iterators:

- `WhereSelectArrayIterator`
- `WhereSelectListIterator`
- `WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`

In case of `List<T>`, `WhereSelectListIterator` iterator is created. It uses list's iterator to iterate over the list and apply predicate and selector. This is a `MoveNext` method implementation:

```
while (this.enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    TSource current = this.enumerator.Current;
    if ((this.predicate == null) || this.predicate(current))
    {
        base.current = this.selector(current);
        return true;
    }
}
```

As you can see, *it does not preserve information about number of items, which matched predicate*, thus it does not know count of items in filtered sequence.